# Port not accessible on Linux server

Tags: linux, iptables, port

I started local server using php on my server

```
php -S 0.0.0.0 8283 -t testServer/
```

using `curl localhost:8283` I am able to get the result of the `index.php` file

but when I access it using my server ip I am not able to access that port .

Any when I do `netstat -tuplen` . I can see that port as well .

**How can I make port 8283 available through http request ?**

I have used this

```
# /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8283 -j ACCEPT
# service iptables save
# service iptables restart
```

and still it did not work

**And this is output from telnet on my server**

```
telnet XX.XX.X.XXX 8283
Trying XX.XX.X.XXX...
Connected to XX.XX.X.XXX.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /

HTTP/0.9 200 OK
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.19
Content-type: text/html

Hello World !Connection closed by foreign host.
```

**this one is from my PC**

```
telnet XX.XX.X.XXX 8283
Trying XX.XX.X.XXX...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

**NMAP Result**

```
sudo nmap -p 8283 XX.XX.X.XXX

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-02-04 19:18 IST
Nmap scan report for srv1.domain.com (XX.XX.X.XXX)
Host is up (0.035s latency).
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
8283/tcp filtered unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.37 seconds
```

**IPTABLES OUTPUT**

```
/sbin/iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:8282 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8283 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Why are you not using Apache?

Comment: No actually I am going to use another application on that port . For now I am testing with php server to check if I can access that port .

Answer (score 1):

Your `localhost` parameter to the `-S` option is telling PHP to only listen to localhost, or 127.0.0.1. If you want it available externally, you need to use either the external IP address / hostname or "0.0.0.0", though a quick read through the manual page doesn't explicitly indicate 0.0.0.0 will work.

Comment: Hi sorry , I edited the question . I used php -S 0.0.0.0 8080 -t testServer/

Comment: Can you see port 8080 listening to 0.0.0.0 in your netstat output? If so, please add the output of `iptables -L -n` to your question.

Comment: Hi Please check , I have included the iptables output .

Comment: Now you've gone and changed the port you're talking about. Are you trying to get to port 8080 or 8283 from the web browser?

Comment: I tried every port 8080 , 8283 , 8282 . But none of them worked . I just need to open a single port through which I can access the server .

Comment: Stop changing the port. Pick one port and use it.

Comment: I am currently trying to work with port 8283 . As you can see it is listed in iptables . I have my php server running on same port . I am able to access it using telnet and curl on my server but not from my local machine and browser .

Comment: When you pull up the page in your browser, what is the error you get? If you simply get a blank page, what shows up in the window when you "View Source"?

Comment: Chrome says "This webpage is not available"

Comment: It is not able to connect to server on that port . Any ideas how this can happen even if I have allowed it in iptables ? Also it is not accessible through nmap query as well .

Comment: Ok, something is wrong with your network. The web page is avialable, the port is open. This is demonstrated by the successful `telnet` on the server.

Comment: Okay thanks for your replies . Appreciate it . I will check if I can get the exact issue .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just test if you can use the port, use Netcat:

**On your server**

```
nc -l 0.0.0.0 8283
```

*Note*: The `-l` switch instructs netcat to *listen* to port 8080.

**On your client**

```
telnet 1.2.3.4 8283
```

*or*

```
nc 1.2.3.4 8283
```